# Cardinal direction algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, compass-geolocation

This weekend I spend a few minutes thrashing together an algorithm that would take in a heading (in degrees) and return a String for the cardinal direction (I'm using it in an android compass application I'm using). What I ended up with was this:

```
private String headingToString(Float heading)
{
    String strHeading = "?";
    Hashtable<String, Float> cardinal = new Hashtable<String, Float>();
    cardinal.put("North_1", new Float(0));
    cardinal.put("Northeast", new Float(45));
    cardinal.put("East", new Float(90));
    cardinal.put("Southeast", new Float(135));
    cardinal.put("South", new Float(180));
    cardinal.put("Southwest", new Float(225));
    cardinal.put("West", new Float(270));
    cardinal.put("Northwest", new Float(315));
    cardinal.put("North_2", new Float(360));

    for (String key: cardinal.keySet())
    {
        Float value = cardinal.get(key);
        if (Math.abs(heading - value) < 30)
        {
            strHeading = key;
            if (key.contains("North_"))
            {
                strHeading = "North";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return strHeading;
}
```

My question is, is this the best way of doing this? It must have been done many times before although I haven't done a search for examples on the web yet. Have any other people tried this and found a neater solution?

Edit for The Reverand's Thilo's, shinjin's and Chrstoffer's responses:

**The Solution**

```
public static String headingToString2(double x)
{
    String directions[] = {"N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N"};
    return directions[ (int)Math.round((  ((double)x % 360) / 45)) ];
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's fine in most cases, though to make it optimized and (IMO) cleaner, what you could do is find a function to relate the input heading to one used in the map.

For example: 
(I'm pretty sure this is right, but you'll want to check it)

```
45* (int)Math.round((  ((double)x % 360) / 45))
```

What this does is first `x % 360` makes sure the heading is within a valid range. then

```
45 * round(.../45)
```

finds the closest multiple of 45.

Now change your map to be

```
  HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>()
  map.put(0, "North")
  map.put(45, "Northeast")
  etc...
```

So, now your algorithm becomes a fast mathemtical calculation rather than iterating through the map. Furthermore, you don't need as Hashtable here since it provides constructs for concurrency (if I remember correctly) and in your case it would actually cause a performance decrease.

Once again, the performance hit may be completely negligible for your needs.

Edit for Thilo's and shinjin's suggestions:

Instead of multiplying by 45, just keep the rest of the equation, which gives you values for 0-7, and make an array of your strings.

```
String directions[] = {"N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"}
return directions[ (int)Math.round((  ((double)x % 360) / 45)) % 8 ]
```

and you've got your problem solved in two lines.

One note: Modulus won't work correctly for negative numbers. If our input heading is negative, you'll need to make it positive first.

Comment: +1. Very nice. Taking this a step further, add another small conversion to the function and he can just get an index into an array of Strings: `String[] directions = { "N", "NE", "E" ... }`

Comment: If you omit the multiplication by 45, then you can use a simple array instead of a hash map.

Comment: You need an additional "N" in that array. Headings 337.5 and up will round to 8.

Comment: There's two typos in this solution that cause incorrect results and IndexOutOfBoundsException:
1) Missing "W" in the array:
`String directions[] = {"N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"}`
2) Index 8 should wrap around back to 0
`return directions[ (int)Math.round((  ((double)x % 360) / 45)) % 8 ]`

Comment: @Walmart_Hobo you meant %7?

Comment: @XCore Nope, mod 8 is correct. Valid indexes are [0, 7], 0%8=0, 1%8=1, ..., 7%8=7, 8%8=0, as desired.

Comment: @Walmart_Hobo whops sorry, miscounted the array.

Comment: @Walmart_Hobo I edited the answer to fix the error, works great now

Answer (score 10):

Most of the answers here are off by 22.5 degrees for their 45 degree intervals, and map e.g. 0-45 as N, rather than [337.5-360],[0-22.5] to N. You need to offset before doing the math to correct for this.

Here's a solution that uses 22.5 degree intervals, such as you might see for wind directions:

```
  private String formatBearing(double bearing) {
    if (bearing < 0 && bearing > -180) {
      // Normalize to [0,360]
      bearing = 360.0 + bearing;
    }
    if (bearing > 360 || bearing < -180) {
      return "Unknown";
    }

    String directions[] = {
      "N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
      "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW",
      "N"};
    String cardinal = directions[(int) Math.floor(((bearing + 11.25) % 360) / 22.5)];
    return cardinal + " (" + formatBearing.format(bearing) + " deg)";
  }
```

Comment: is it normal that your array of directions contains N twice ?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe add 15 degrees up front to avoid North_1 and North_2.

Answer (score 0):

The previous examples are not accurate, here is a more accurate solution in JavaScript.

```
function getCardinalDirection(input) {
    var directions = ["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N"];
    var index = Math.floor( ((input-22.5)%360) / 45 );
    return directions[index+1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in java:

```
String _directions[] = {"N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"};

public String getHeading(int hea) {
  return _directions[(int)Math.floor((hea % 360) / 45)];
}
```

In "java" case u must need to create a Class.

in javascript:

```
var _directions = ["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"];

function getDirection (hea) {
  return _directions[Math.floor((hea % 360) / 45)];
};
```